# python Nonetype check on custom exception handling not working

Tags: python, django

I have been running this simple code for exception handling. It runs correctly in every scenario except when there need to check for Nonetype. I have used every line of code but nothing worked for me. Below I just kept simple, can you please help me here why it is not going inside if condition.? [updated] : Placed more print statements to give more insight on the issue. It is being called like "raise CustomExcpetion(excep=e)" in django

```
class CustomExcpetion(PermissionDenied):
    def __init__(self, excep, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST):
        message={"message": "error observed"}
        print ("Inside custom exception")
        print (excep)
        excepType = type(excep)
        print ("exception type found : ")
        print(excepType)
        
        if excep is None:
             print ("none exception found")
             self.detail = message
        print ("none exception NOT found")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried: `if !excep:` or the opposite `if excep`?

Comment: What is `PermissionDenied`? It appears something you aren't showing is assuming that `excep` will be a string. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: opposite, it is going through, but I need to check for None. Actually this block I am using in django and above function triggers when we raise exceptions from other class.

Comment: "It runs correctly in every scenario except when there need to check for Nonetype. " - I can't understand. If you pass an exception for the `excep` value, then of course the `excep` value is not `None`. An exception that has a **message** of `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'` **is completely different from** a `NoneType` object (i.e., `None`). It's like if you wanted to measure how tall a tree is, by looking at a picture of it.